# how to find all the child nodes in hierarchical tree

Tags: mysql, sql, hierarchical-data

I have a table that is self-referencing by fk parentId.
Given a given id, I need to extract all of its child nodes.
I know the graph has exactly three levels: root, middleNode, leaf
so i tried this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table AS root 
LEFT JOIN table AS middle
  ON middle.parentId = root.id
LEFT JOIN table AS leaf
  ON leaf.parentId = middle.id
WHERE root.id = 1
```

but in this way I do not have a row for each node...

moreover, this implementation does not take into account 2 things:

1. it is linked to the structure of 3 levels
2. it does not seem to me the best solution if I search in the middle of the tree

Comment: If you have a question, please include it in the question.  Sample data and desired results also help.

Comment: If max depth of tree is small, like 4-5, then `LEFT JOIN` as many times necessary.

Comment: Lookup recursive CTE

Comment: Are you looking to find all nodes in the heirarchy, or just all nodes from the start point down?

Comment: @SalmanA He doesn't want a `left join` what he really wants is a `union`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 3 levels, you can have it with

```
    SELECT * FROM 
-- root
(
SELECT * 
FROM your_table WHERE id = 1 
) as root
UNION ALL
-- level1
(
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE parentId = 1 ) 
)
UNION ALL
-- level2
(
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE parentId IN (SELECT id FROM your_table WHERE parentId = 1 ) 
)
```

But for deep depth, I would suggest you implement common approach such as **Nested Set Model** (need to add extra columns), please [take a look on this](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)

Comment: This doesn't meet 2 on the question, The option requires you to start at the top of the tree.

Comment: have you tried it, changing the 3 `your_table` into `table` as your case? (in mine, it shows root first, then level1, then level2). Or I don't really understand what do you mean by **The option requires you to start at the top of the tree**

Comment: I may have misunderstood the question, if OP only wants to go from that point down yours would work, though you are doing some unneeded work `SELECT id FROM your_table WHERE id = 1 ` is redundant, you are selecting your provided where clause.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go down the tree from the point you are at, you can do that using a temporary table.

```
CREATE TABLE tempTable (id int, parentid int);

INSERT INTO tempTable (id, parentid)
SELECT id, parentID FROM tree WHERE id = @input;
SET @LastCount=0;
SELECT @Count = COUNT(1) FROM tempTable;
WHILE @LastCount != @Count DO
    INSERT INTO tempTable (id, parentid)
    SELECT id,parentid from tree where id in (SELECT parentid FROM TempTable) AND ID NOT IN (SELECT id FROM TempTable);
    @LastCount = @Count;
    SELECT @Count = COUNT(1) FROM tempTable;
END WHILE;

SELECT * FROM tempTable;
DROP tempTable;
```

This will loop over and over, going further down the heirarchy, adding rows that have a parent currently in the table, so long as those rows are not already there, and ending the loop when it adds no new rows (last loop row count = current loop row count) This has the benefit of not caring at all what the size of the hierarchy is, it can be 3 levels or 30, nor does it care where you start, it always goes down one more level.

If you want the whole hierarchy that includes that node, you can loop your way up the hierarchy until you find one with no parent (if you have multiple trees in the same table, say multiple warehouses with aisles, and shelves, each warehouse the top level):

```
SET @next = @input;
WHILE @next IS NOT NULL DO
 SET @topID = @next;
 SELECT @next = parentID FROM tree WHERE id=@topID;
END WHILE

CREATE TABLE tempTable (id int, parentid int);

INSERT INTO tempTable (id, parentid);
SELECT id, parentID FROM table WHERE id = @topID;
SET @LastCount=0;
SELECT @Count = COUNT(1) FROM tempTable;
WHILE @LastCount != @Count DO
    INSERT INTO tempTable (id, parentid)
    SELECT id,parentid from tree where id in (SELECT parentid FROM TempTable) AND ID NOT IN (SELECT id FROM TempTable);
    @LastCount = @Count;
    SELECT @Count = COUNT(1) FROM tempTable;
END WHILE;

SELECT * FROM tempTable;
DROP tempTable;
```

This will run up to the top of the tree, then loop it's way back down level by level. Either one can use a counter variable inside the while loop to find the relative level from the point you started at.

SQLFiddle doesn't allow some of these functions to work properly for MySQL, but I do have a MsSQL fiddle showing this function works - [MsSql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6216c/1)

Comment: I will admit I am not a mysql expert, and sqlfiddle does not like running this kind of solution on mysql so I haven't tested it, but I did translate it to mysql syntax from a working mssql solution.